# Centralising CUPS config

Tags: cups

I have a LAN with a few Ubuntu machines on. They each need to be set up with the same printers.

I would like to have a script that copies a centrally stored config to each machine so that they're all doing the same thing with the same drivers.

Looking in /etc/cups/ I see quite a lot of files including duplicates but with `.O` appended for some reason (backups?).

Is it as simple as

```
service cups stop
cp -ar /path/to/source/cups /etc/cups
service cups start
```

or are any of the config things in there necessarily unique to the machine they are running on?

Comment: Why not directly have a centralized installation of CUPS? i.e. only one printing server all your machines could send their jobs to?

Comment: The individual machines still need configging to point to the centralised server... (I find CUPS flaky at the best of times, and it regularly loses printer definitions, which is why I'm looking for a way to automate this)

Comment: With a centralized server, it's a lot easier, the configuration is in a single place. The clients' configuration is really lightweight: the IP address of the server.

Comment: Of course, if you say that the server loses the printer definitions, that's a bigger problem >.<

Comment: Should be a back-up of the printing configuration in a Samba Server?